# Pandas Dataframe is not pretty displayed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, read.csv

Well I am trying to create a dataframe in pandas and print it reading a csv file, however it is not pretty displayed

This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("weather.csv")
print(df)
```

And this is my output:

[image: And this is my output (image)]

What can I do?

Comment: Be sure to have https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html  open for further reference :)

Answer (score 2):

A sample of `weather.csv` would help but I believe that this will solve the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("weather.csv", sep=';')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time try to provide your data in text. You need to change separator, default is ','. So try this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('weather.csv', sep=';')
```